# Parse font file properties

Tags: python, qt, fonts, embed

I am working on a open source application (OpenLP.org) and I would like to be able to embed a font in to a file. I am aware of legal restrictions, my question is not about this.

Basically given a font file, I would like to read the property "Font Embeddability". I found this property in windows by right clicking a font file and then clicking properties (see the screen shot below).

OpenLP uses Qt and Python. It doesn't seem like QFont gives you access to these properties. So I'm guessing I'm going to have to parse the file using pythons struct module.

Any suggestions?

[image: Windows File Properties]

Comment: Maybe find a resource that defines the file's structure then `... parse the file using pythons struct module.`??

Comment: Thats one route I've been looking at, but with out much success!

Comment: I've managed to find a utility http://carnage-melon.tom7.org/embed/ which is public domain and has the source available. I'll post any code I come up with!